# Saving entire webpage with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, caching, afnetworking

I use web views in my app and I want the user to be able to open a page in offline mode if he has opened it already before. So I need to somehow store entire page, including images. Is there any easy way to do it where I don't have to parse entire html looking for 's and downloading them separately? I was doing it in my previous project by using ASIWebPageRequest, but I was thinking about moving from ASIHTTPRequest to AFNetworking, starting from this project.

Comment: did you finally achieve that using AFNetworking?

Comment: After some studies on the subject, I found NSURLCache could actually do the trick for me. Problem is, I'd have to control the disk usage and check all the time if I need to make bigger disk capacity - every time I saved anything. I decided to use database for this project instead and if I'll need this functionality in another project, I'll probably go back to ASIWebPageRequest (or ProxyingUIWebView, from same author).

Comment: thanks for the answer @johnyu, can you please explain how did you use databases for this purpose? what information did you save?

Comment: Well, it's actually an approach that works in my specific case. The projest is still i progress, so a few things I am still unsure of, i.e. what exactly will my data look like. The current concept is that it might not actually even be html, just text with html-like tags that I will find out from what kind of data I'm displaying (and therefore how I'm supposed to display it). Images will probably have their tags with id like <img>1324<img>, so I will then look in another table for image with id 1324 where I saved it as NSData.

Comment: thank you @johnyu, I'm evaluating different approaches for downloading and saving in some way an entire website

Comment: Well, I recommend checking ASIWebPageRequest, worked without any problems for me. :) Only con is that the entire page is first downloaded and then displayed. ProxyingUIWebView is supposed to bypass this problem, but I haven't tried it yet.